# Sequelize is not applying setters in controller

Tags: sequelize.js

Something that feels strange (to me at least) is happening when I am using `Sequelize` with some `getters` and `setters`. They are all working as expected - encrypting and decrypting values as they are stored to the database and decrypting them when sending them to the client.

However, exactly when the decryption happens seems unclear to me as my previously working queries are now failing. For instance - the request below should bring back my decrypted e-mails (because I haven't asked for raw values) but it provides a list of encrypted values. Values sent to the client are decrypted, but just prior to sending them they appear to remain encrypted on the backend controller.

```
let userEmails = await LoginMethod.findAll({
    attributes: ['email'],
});
console.log("LOGIN METHOD EMAILS", userEmails); // Encrypted
res.json({userEmails}); // Decrypted when checked in the client's browser console
```

**UPDATE:** I can get the values I'm expecting (i.e. the decrypted values), using Anatoly's suggestion in the comments:

```
var nodedata = userEmails.map(x => x.get());
```

However, this still doesn't solve my issue when I query the database with a value, for instance:

```
let userLoginMethods = await LoginMethod.findAll({
  where: {
     email: 'string'
  }
});
```

This will not produce any results, even though I know the email exists in the database. I assume that it is querying the encrypted values and not the decrypted ones as everything was working prior to encryption. **How do I use `where: {...}` with sequelize getters and setters?**

This has effectively broken my platform as I can no longer use the text value querying - i.e. searching for a user by email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone

Happy to provide more code if needed.

---

Controller code:

```
let userEmails = await LoginMethod.findAll({
    attributes: ['email'],
});
```

Sequelize Model:

```
...
email: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  get() {
    const aes256gcm = require('../services/aes256gcm');
    const storedValue = this.getDataValue('email');
    return aes256gcm.aes256gcm(process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY).decrypt(storedValue);
  },
  set(value) {
    const aes256gcm = require('../services/aes256gcm');
    this.setDataValue('email', aes256gcm.aes256gcm(process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY).encrypt(value));
  }
},
...
```

I have also tried this:

```
...
  get() {
    const aes256gcm = require('../services/aes256gcm');
    const storedValue = this.getDataValue('email');
    aes256gcm.aes256gcm(process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY).decrypt(storedValue)
    .then((decryptedValue) => {
      return decryptedValue;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  },
...
```

I've also played around with `raw: false` but that hasn't helped.

Comment: What result do you get if you output to console `userEmails.map(x => x.get())`?

Comment: Still the encrypted values unfortunately: `LoginMethod { dataValues: {email: 'ikHfi1J_NgFe6XFmzi1jM5HNHZrivupzFoSDJvmIdEYedAa1uRnRNktwqEY1' },`

Comment: `dataValues` means you still look at the Sequelize model instance and not at the plain object after calling `get({ plain: true })`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've worked that out and I now have the plain object. I could rewrite all my Sequelize queries but surely there's a way to tell Sequelize to do this automatically? For instance when I am trying to see if a record exists with a particular e-mail I used to just use `LoginMethod.findAll({where: {email: EMAIL }})` (this isn't working because test@gmail doesn't equal the encrypted value. I'd rather continue doing this without selecting all records, then filtering manually in my controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sequelize hooks. With getter, you have to call `user.getDataValue('username')` to get the *getter* value. Take a look [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/#getters)

Here is the hook version, it would work as intended.

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', 
  {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    // other properties
  }, 
  {
  tableName: 'users',
  hooks : {
    afterFind : (user, options) => {
        if (user.email) {
          user.email = aes256gcm.aes256gcm(process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY).decrypt(user.email);
        }
    },
    beforeFind : (user, options) => {
        if (user.where && user.where.email) {
          user.where.email = aes256gcm.aes256gcm(process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY).encrypt(user.where.email);
        }
    },
    beforeCreate : (user, options) => {
        if (user.email) {
          user.email = aes256gcm.aes256gcm(process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY).encrypt(user.email);
        }
    },
  }
});

module.exports = User;
```

[Sequelize hooks](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/)

[Complete list of hooks](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6/src/hooks.js#L7)

Comment: Same issue unfortunately... I think perhaps because I'm using GCM where there is a random IV which means each time the value is encrypted there is a different outcome, the random iv is then stored within the value. i.e. `beforeFind` will encrypt my raw text email example@gmail.com but it won't be the same value as the encrypted one in the database. How can I use a hook to decrypt the database values prior to the `.findAll(where:{...})` is ran?

Comment: @OliverTrampleasure I have updated the answer. In the `beforeFind` hook you need to encrypt the email to find the matched one.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Unfortunately still doesn't work, the problem is that each time I encrypt the value there is a different result. For instance if I run the same request with the same email the encrypted search value changes. The first is `5JhZAzb_LH76pweyufa7B6RUEcI2PepoR4pGIv-K_M7r1YULatqHXXQbRrce` and the second `5c_qwiveMu37ZGNefBLfS023e-w5ZZiIZYuBuiFQ-1_qAXGy4sGdV3oPcHMI`. Were you using a different encryption method which didn't use randomly generated initialisation vectors (IV)?

Comment: The answer is correct!  I have a lot of questions here. The first is why you are encrypting. Also, it's not hash it will not be consistent, what matters is whether you get the same email after decrypting the encrypted email. It would be more helpful if you would share your `aes256gcm` service.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the randomly generated initialisation vectors (IV) correctly, this will create different encrypted text each time. So, only equality you can do is with decrypted texts.

That says, to fetch records with `email = 'string'`, you need the DB to provide the function or create a custom function in DB side so that you can do `decrypt(email) = 'string'` in SQL.

I couldn't tell which DB you are using but if you are using Postgres, check around this package https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html. I didn't check if Postgres has the IV encryption.

Or if you need to create a custom function, look here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html.

Then once you have/create the `decrypt` function, you can do

```js
const userLoginMethods = await LoginMethod.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('decrypt', Sequelize.col('email')), Op.eq, 'string')
});
```